# When updating a string variable pointer, do I need to manually release the memory of the string sub-face value?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *demo = "demo";
    fprintf(stdout, "string point: %p\n", demo);
    demo = "Hello World";
    fprintf(stdout, "string point: %p\n", demo);
    return 0;
}
```

The two strings are located at different memory addresses.

```
string point: 0x55b2b9207004
string point: 0x55b2b920701b
```

Will this cause a waste of memory?

Do I need to use the `free(void *ptr)` function of `stdlib.h` to release it manually?

Comment: YOu can only call `free()` if you assigned the pointer with `malloc()`.

Comment: There's no way to release the memory of a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard function `free()` can only be used for pointers allocated by previous calls to `malloc/calloc/realloc`, and this is not the case. The strings in your program are allocated statically (probably in the read-only memory section of your program) or may be allocated on the stack.

The important thing to remember is that dynamic allocations (allocations on the heap) are always done explicitly by calling `malloc()` etc. either by you directly, or by a function indirectly (that calls `malloc` at some point). These dynamic pointers must always be `free`d when you're done using them.

Comment: "These dynamic pointers must always be `free`d when you're done using them." They usually *should* be, but if the program is about to terminate it's (almost certainly) safe to assume that the OS will deallocate everything.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right, it's almost completely pointless to release certain types of resources when you know that your program is going to exit in one second or something. Nevertheless it's a good habit to always free memory (so you remember to do it when it's necessary), plus if you need to move the code somewhere else in the future and your program isn't going to exit soon anymore after a certain resource allocation, you'll have a resource leak (memory leaks, files opened forever, etc).